# SQL Server performance optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, hash, query-optimization

I have table to store files. I store SHA256 hash in a column to uniquely identify a file. Before inserting new file I check for duplicate file using the hash and if it exists already I don't insert.

For example my query can be:

```
select filename 
from filetable 
where filehash = 'xyz'
```

Right now there are only a few hundred files.

When this number grows to a few hundred thousand next year, how do I optimize the performance?

Comment: Performance of what?  Do you have a query in mind?

Comment: Do you have unique index on the hash column? if not, you need to add it

Comment: just add an index

Comment: I could be wrong but the question sounds like a bad plan. If the goal is to have a unique identifier for each file then there is no need for a SHA256 instead you can use the auto id feature of a table to create a unique identifier every time you add a new row.  If the goal is to make sure some data is unique (eg I don't want to reuse the same name so I will hash that name and see if it already exists), that too can be managed  by SQL server quite well with a unique index.  So I'm interested to know your use case. There is probably a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that specific query just add the index:

```
create index ix1 on filetable (filehash);
```

If you want to make it even faster (probably not needed) you can create a *covering index* instead:

```
create index ix1 on filetable (filehash, filename);
```